# Python saving 13 bit depth .mat data as TIFF converts to 16 bit

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, scipy, kinect-v2

I am importing depth data from Kinect V2 saved as `.MAT` files using `scipy.io.loadmat` into my python 3.5 code. When I print out the `.MAT` data I get an `uint16` array with values ranging from `0 - 8192`. This is expected as the Kinect V2 gives a 13 bit depth image data. Now, when I save this as a `TIFF` file using
`cv2.imwrite('depth_mat.tif' , depth_arr)` and read it using 
`depth_im = tifffile.imread('depth_mat.tif')`.The range of values are scaled up. In my original `.MAT` file the maximum value is `7995` and after saving and reading the `.TIFF` file the maximum value becomes `63728`. This throws off my calculations for mapping Kinect Depth to actual distance in real world. Any insight about this would help me a lot.

I have to do some image processing in between, hence it is necessary to preserve the original values. Also instead of using `cv2.imwrite()`,if `tifffile.imsave()` is used to save the `.MAT` file, the image is entirely dark.

I am using python 3.5 on a Win 64 machine

Comment: Have you tried normalizing the values between 0 and 1 before calling `tifffile.imsave`? (The example at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile is saving a matrix of values between 0 and 1)

Comment: Have not tried normalizing as the example just initializes a random generator. In my case it is raw depth values from a kinect sensor and I can't think of  why saving it as a `.tif' is scaling up the intensity.